# android application dividing the project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, project-management

I am working in a team to create an andorid application.Initially we worked on a particular single system for developing.

Problem is that we want to divide the work among all of the team members so that they can work on a particular section of the development in seperate systems.
But we dont know how to divide a project into different systems.Also we would like to know how to club these works together after completion to form the application.We are using eclpse for developing.

Please help us.We are having a great problem with this.

Please help us.

Comment: Have you tried using Git? Seems like that would be your solution. Making branches and then merging back into the main program in the end sounds like what you need.

Comment: Did you read the explanation for the tags you added? "Project management is the discipline of planning, organizing, securing, and managing resources to achieve specific goals. Such questions are now off-topic on SO, please use [Project Management Stack Exchange Site](http://pm.stackexchange.com)."

Comment: This question is not about code. For conceptual questions, you may try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use GIT repositories in a common server. There you can get your own copy of the project and you can modify your copy. Then you can update your changes in the server. Please refer to http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Answer (score 0):

@user3285824 : You need a `Revision Control or Source Control` Tool. Please check out [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) which is the best tool to develop separate modules in eclipse with team members.

Follow the [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php) to install SVN in eclipse.